# fetched data by using "GET" method get lost when i reopen the app from background

Tags: ios, get, nsurlconnection

here i am fetching the data from server using GET method but when i minimise, the app goes in background and after i reopen i don't see any data which i fetched before, i only see the data for the first time and when i minimise and reopen it get lost here is my code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://198.178.4.9:89/mybite_joomla/cron/webapi.php?task=webapi.viewProfile"]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                 timeoutInterval:10
                              ];


  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

  [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];{


for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray) {

    nameTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey:@"name"];

    usernameTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey : @"username"];

    emailTextView.text=[jsonArray valueForKey : @"email"];

    cityTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey : @"city"];

    stateTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey : @"state"];

    countryTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey : @"country"];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `NSDictionary *jsonArray` as a property with `(nonatomic,strong)` and use that property to retrieve data or fill textFields.

Second thing if your app remains very long time in background and get in suspended state then you should have to store data in database. Because once app got suspended then it deallocate instance memory.

Second main important thing is you should not use `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` as it is unimplemented.

As [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy) states,

> Specifies that not only should the local cache data be ignored, but that proxies and other intermediates should be instructed to disregard their caches so far as the protocol allows. 
>   This constant is unimplemented and shouldn’t be used.

So, you can pass `0` as parameter to `cachePolicy` or can construct request like if `timeoutInterval` is not mandatory.

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://198.178.4.9:89/mybite_joomla/cron/webapi.php?task=webapi.viewProfile"]];
```

Comment: can i store  the data using NSUserDefaults will it be helpful in my case if the app remains in background for long time and get in suspended state @Lion

Comment: Yes you can use `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: and No use of declaring NSDictionary *jsonArray as property...even if app goes in background for few seconds i lose data @Lion

Comment: Don't set cache policy. I think it is because of it.

Comment: Tell me how should i do that for any one textField, (fetching data and storing it using NSUserDefaults and showing it in textField )  i am new to iOS help me @Lion

Comment: Just google it that how to store and retrieve data in nsuserdefaults, you will get many links. Main thing is it should not happen like this that you go to background for few seconds and your data becomes nil!!

Comment: no storing it using NSUserDefaults also not working @Lion

Comment: still looking for answer

Comment: I think you have different kind of issue. May be memory related.

Comment: @ Lion  how to figure it out

Comment: I don't have idea that what causing this kind of issue. I have never faced before.

Comment: i appreciate your help Mr. i think this was the original problem yesterday of that LOGOUT related question which i had asked and you answered. Still that is an issue also. @Lion